# Need Azure powershell command to get the Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-aks

Please help me to find the azure powershell comand to get the list of Azure Kubernetes Service running in the azure tenant using powershell. Please help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `get-azurermresource` with a `where-object` to filter down results:

```
Get-AzureRmResource | ? resourcetype -eq 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters'
```

but you'd have to create a loop around all subscriptions.

or you could use new AzureRmGraph module:

```
Search-AzureRmGraph -Query "where type =~ 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters'
```